# How to stop backslashes from cancelling in conversion from QString to char array?

Tags: c++, qt, char, qstring

I am writing a QT widgets application that includes serial communication with an Arduino. [I found a good header and cpp file on GitHub](https://github.com/manashmndl/SerialPort) that makes communicating with an Arduino MUCH easier than it would be with QSerialPort.

However one difficulty that this presents is that the port name must be given as a char array in the format "\\.\COM1" for example. So I'm trying to add those backslashes before the COM port name, with this code:

```
QString currentPort = "\\\\.\\" + QString(ui->serialPortDropdown->itemText(index));
portName = currentPort.toLocal8Bit().data();
```

After initialising the array with this at the top of my cpp file:

```
char *portName;
```

After adding a few qDebug()s here and there, the QString is being set to how it should be, `"\\\\.\\COM1"` for example. But the char array is returning as `"\\.\COM1"`. So the backslashes are cancelling other backslashes.

How do I overcome this?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: It's not canceling, backslash is an escape character, thus you need 2 backslashes for every output of 1 backslash. see \r, \n, \t, \0 etc. \\\\\\\\.\\\\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QString is being **escaped**. That is, special characters (including ) are specified using their escape sequence ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the Wikipedia article about escaping).

Since the escape sequence for the backslash character is **\\**, you just have to double your backslashes:

```
QString currentPort = "\\\\\\\\.\\\\" + QString(ui->serialPortDropdown->itemText(index));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior in C++ source files. And there is even more of them:

> Escape sequences are used to represent certain special characters within string literals and character literals.
>
> The following escape sequences are available (extra escape sequences may be provided with implementation-defined semantics):

```
 Escape      | Description                 |Representation
sequence     |                             |
-------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
  \'         | single quote                |byte 0x27 in ASCII encoding
  \"         | double quote                |byte 0x22 in ASCII encoding
  \?         | question mark               |byte 0x3f in ASCII encoding
  \\         | backslash                   |byte 0x5c in ASCII encoding
  \a         | audible bell                |byte 0x07 in ASCII encoding
  \b         | backspace                   |byte 0x08 in ASCII encoding
  \f         | form feed - new page        |byte 0x0c in ASCII encoding
  \n         | line feed - new line        |byte 0x0a in ASCII encoding
  \r         | carriage return             |byte 0x0d in ASCII encoding
  \t         | horizontal tab              |byte 0x09 in ASCII encoding
  \v         | vertical tab                |byte 0x0b in ASCII encoding
  \nnn       | arbitrary octal value       |byte nnn
  \xnn       | arbitrary hexadecimal value |byte nn
  \unnnn     | universal character name (arbitrary Unicode value); may result in several characters
             |                             |code point U+nnnn
  \Unnnnnnnn | universal character name (arbitrary Unicode value); may result in several characters
             |                             |code point U+nnnnnnnn
```

Source: [Escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

If this is a problem, then C++11 introduced a new type of string literal : **raw string literal**

> Raw string literal. Used to avoid escaping of any character. Anything between the delimiters becomes part of the string.

Syntax :

`prefix R " delimiter ( raw_characters ) delimiter "`

- *prefix*    -   (optional) One of L, u8, u, U
- *delimiter*     -   A character sequence made of any source character but parentheses, backslash and spaces (can be empty, and at most 16 characters long)
- *raw_characters*     -   Any character sequence, except that it must not contain the closing sequence `) delimiter "`

Source: [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

---

To solve the problem there are 2 solutions

1. In every place where a backslash is needed insert 2 backlslashes : `"\\\\\\\\.\\\\"`
2. Use a raw string : `R"(\\\\.\\)"`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in an "ordinary" string literal as yours a backslash introduces "special" characters like, for example, a new line `\n`. To get one backslash, you have to enter two consecutive backslashes then, i.e. `\\` to get `\`.

To overcome this, either enter each backslash twice, or use the [raw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) format for specifying string literals:

```
int main() {

    const char* raw = R"foo(\\\\.\\)foo";
    cout << "raw: " << raw << endl;

    const char* notRaw = "\\\\.\\";
    cout << "not raw: " << notRaw << endl;

}
```

Output:

```
raw: \\\\.\\
not raw: \\.\
```

Note that the "foo("-part is custom; it can be anything of your choice which will not be contained in the inner part of the string literal.